# In jQuery, how can I make it so a click function can activate a resizable property

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Let's say I have a `div` that when it's clicked on it adds the `.resizable()` function to the `div`, thus being able to be resized.  Would anyone have a code example of this?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will do:

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#clickme").click(function() {
      $("#makethisresizable").resizable();
    });
  });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
  #makethisresizable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="clickme">Click me</div>

<div id="makethisresizable">Make this resizable</div>
```